# left and right border appears when i fit my svg in window

Tags: html, css, image

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0;}
svg {top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100% }
#b_txt{
    position:absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:300px;
}
```

This b_txt is just a input box in html.

My svg is appearing 
 [that way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTCcv.png)

what can i do to fit?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you attempting to make the svg fit to the width of the screen?

Comment: Yeah, i want to fill the browser window

Comment: Can you provide your html code, so that I can take a look at exactly what's going on?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15vWeQdcfnsQfXhBkEeQ2lDjXyNB3iqDN
Here it is, the forum doesn't allow put that many lines of codes, so i puted in google drive.

Answer (score 1):

If this case the ratio of height and width of your `svg` is fixed and you are trying to change the default height and width ratio which is not possible in your case.

If you put

```html
svg{
    top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100% 
}
```

It is setting height to `100%` but ```width: 100%`` do not work, it automatically set width according to default svg ratio.

To fit the svg to screen change the default svg height and width according to your screen.
or 
use only `width: 100%` but this will create height more than your screen.